# Add Asterisk to a path Variable?

Tags: bash, variable

I need to use `*.*` at the end of a Path that is stored in a variable. Also just one "*" should be OK as well.

finally I want to move files in folders with same name. With a static Path like `/share/test/temp/*` the for loop worked.
Now I have different usernames and the search folder for the for loop changes. Therefore I need a varible there.
This doesnt work:

```
    destDir= $Startdir/$username/
a=$destDir/*.*

for file in $a  ; do
  tmp=${file:0:4};
  filenew=${file%.*}"($tmp)";
  mkdir -- "$filenew";
  mv -- "$file" "$filenew";
done
```

I have tried to escape, single and double marks and backticks.

```
a=$destDir/*.*      # not working
a="$destDir/\*"     # not working
a= $destDir'/\*'    # not working
a="$destDir/'\*.\*" # not working
```

How can I make a pure sting with asterix in it, that will be substitued in the for loop?
Or is there any other option to pass a variable to a for loop that stores a path and for knows that he has to search very file in that path?

I would perfer a for loop than `find $destDir -name ..`

Comment: Don't put spaces after (or before) the `=` in an assignment -- that changes their meaning completely.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what your code is supposed to do. I suggest to show an example directory structure and file list and the expected result. What about `destDir="$Startdir/$username"` `for file in "$destDir"/*.* ; do ...`

Comment: big sorry, I just found the mistake by myself. I have tu use dobble quotes for every file. The problem was not in the for loop directory, but it was in the commands between do and done. This works: `for file in $destDir/*.*; do tmp=$"{file:0:4}"; filenew="${file%.*}""($tmp)"; mkdir -- "$filenew"; mv -- "$file" "$filenew"; done`

Comment: this is just a warkaround for my questen. I still cannot use asterix in variables. In a test script I have tried something like this, that doesnt work. `destDir= 'share/temp/test' ;
destDir=$Startdir/$username/ ;
a="$destDir/*.*" ;
echo $a ;`   How Can I use Asterix or "*.*" in bash in a variable?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are doing. As Gordon pointed out, you cannot use `var= something`, the space breaks the syntax, so your example doesn't make sense. And we need to know if you want `*` (all files) or `*.*` (all files whose name contains a `.`).

Answer (score 0):

There are several stumbling blocks in your script - some of them come into mind immediately:

1. in your script line: "for file in $a; do"  *s in $a are not interpreted by the shell as you expected, instead they are taken literally.
2. Your *.* and * are not equal: *.* requires a dot in the file names while * does not.

Check with a simplified script like this:

```
destDir=$HOME
a=$destDir/*
for file in $a;  do echo $file;  done
```

Warning: if a file name contains whitespace, the for loop will split it into two (or more) file names.

If /share/test/temp/* works for you (which means you have no whitespace in your file names), why not just use:

```
for file in $destdir/*;  do ...yourstuff...; done
```

If you have whitespace, you might try:

```
find $destDir -type f | while read file;  do ...yourstuff...;  done
```